# How to set VLAN PCP value?

Tags: linux, vlan, qos

I am using Intel 82599ES 10-Gigabit adapter on a Linux Machine.I have configured Vlan and the priorities on switch. I have read this http://open-lldp.org/dcb_overview. "When DCB is in operation on a network interface, the skb_priority is mapped to the user priority value which becomes the PCP in the VLAN tag."

I have set vlan interface and used vconfig_set_egress_map eth224.150 0 5 command to do mappping.

But still when i capture the frame I see PCP value as 0. [Vlan tag in captured frame.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jsR0.jpg)
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intel ixgbe driver was the problem.Updating it to the latest version solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A 3-bit user Priority Code Point (PCP) that sets a priority value between 0 and 7, which can be used for Quality of Service (QoS) priority. Please refer to this article as well - http://www.erg.abdn.ac.uk/users/gorry/course/lan-pages/vlan.html

Comment: Thanks for answering !But this is not what I am looking for.I know what is VLAN tag,trunk and all.